# C# - Test to assert component times out after X seconds

Tags: c#, nunit, rhino-mocks

Suppose I have a simple Api class like this, where an external call is made but an exception is thrown after 5 seconds if it doesn't finish:

```
public class Api
{
    private readonly IConnector connector;

    public Api(IConnector connector)
    {
        this.connector = connector;
    }

    public string GetSomething()
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        timer.Elapsed += TimeOut;

        timer.Start();
        //some external call which takes time
        connector.Retrieve();
        timer.Stop();

        return "Something";
    }

    private void TimeOut(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("Timed out!");
    }
}
```

Using NUnit or otherwise, how might I go about testing that the above throws an exception when the request takes 8 seconds, but succeeds when the request takes 3 seconds?

I've tried the below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ApiTests
{
    IConnector mockConnector;
    Api api;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        mockConnector = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IConnector>();
        api = new Api(mockConnector);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Api_RetrieveTakes3Seconds_SomethingReturned()
    {
        mockConnector.Stub(c => c.Retrieve()).Return(Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(c => "Something").Result);
        var response = api.GetSomething();

        Assert.AreEqual("Something", response);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Api_RetrieveTakes8Seconds_TimeOutExceptionThrown()
    {
        mockConnector.Stub(c => c.Retrieve()).Return(Task.Delay(8000).ContinueWith(c => "Something").Result);
        var response = api.GetSomething();

        //assert an exception is thrown on the above
    }

}
```

But this doesn't work as expected, when I debug the task just waits on the stub line for X seconds (before api.GetSomething() is even called)

How can I adjust these tests to get the desired behavior?

As an added bonus, it would be great if it was possible to not have to wait for the rests to run.

Comment: maybe try "mockConnector.Stub(c => c.Retrieve()).Return(()=>Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(c => "Something").Result);" to get your code to wait on the right line?

Answer (score 0):

You can test for an exception with the "Assert.Throws" nunit assert.You can test that a value is returned after x amount of time using a stopwatch like this:

```
[Test]
    public void Api_RetrieveTakes3Seconds_SomethingReturned()
    {
        mockConnector.Stub(c => c.Retrieve()).Return(Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(c => "Something").Result);
        topwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var response = api.GetSomething();
        sw.Stop();
        Assert.That(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, Is.LessThanOrEqualTo(3000));        }

    [Test]
    public void Api_RetrieveTakes8Seconds_TimeOutExceptionThrown()
    {
        mockConnector.Stub(c => c.Retrieve()).Return(Task.Delay(8000).ContinueWith(c => "Something").Result);

        Assert.Throws(Exception, ()=> api.GetSomething());
    }
```

You will need to add in a bit of a buffer since your test is waiting exactly 3 seconds, so you should probably check that the test returns in less then 3.1 seconds or something like that.

Comment: Hmm but this seems to suffer the same problem, the artificial delay doesn't occur when Retrieve() is called on the stub - it just happens when the stub is created. The Retrieve() call is still instant.

Answer (score 0):

For the happy path, try

```
Assert.That(() => api.GetSomething(), Is.EqualTo(expected).After(3).Seconds));
```

You may need to adjust the time as it's subject to latency.

For the failure, you need a inject a mock or fake into api that takes too long and then...

```
Assert.That(() => api.GetSomething(), Throws.Typeof<MyException>());
```

This is all forum code, so watch for errors. :-)

Comment: Thanks, however it's making the mock's stub for Retrieve() take too long which is the problem. How can this be done?

Comment: Not a Rhino guy, but I think some other answers tell you how to do that.